# TinyMCE insert image url adding extra slash and making broken link

Tags: php, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE in my php pages and it's saved to the db.

It all works fine except when you insert an image.

I'm makes a broken link ...I've checked at the url in firebug and this is the output:

```
<img src="\"http://ysite.com/images/preview.jpg\"">
```

should be:

```
<img src="http://ysite.com/images/preview.jpg">
```

It's got extra: \"  at the beginning and end.

Comment: Configure your PHP environment to not automatically add slashes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dont have the option to turn off [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) then you should include a check and handle the stripping of slashes accordingly.

This makes portability of code much easyier if code will hit other setups.

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);
} else {
    $content = $_POST['content'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I've added this: <?php echo stripslashes($content); ?>   but it's not striping the \"  ...is my syntax wrong?

Comment: is `$content` whats holding your posted content? you should un-slash directly from the post

Comment: @Satch3000: You need to fix the input *before* you store it into the DB (which implies that you need to fix the destroyed content in your DB as well).

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `html_entity_decode()`